# WebApp URL showing error "You need permission"

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, permissions

I have been using a web app URL using the following
var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();

to generate an approve and reject URLs which are then included in the email that is sent from the script. The "Deploy as web app" settings are
Execute the app as: Me
AND
Who has access to the app: Anyone within the organization

This code has been working fine for past few months since we rolled it out.

Today suddenly, when the person clicks on approve or reject link, following error is being displayed. What could be the reason for this, given that we have not made any changes to the code or settings. Did Google roll out any changes? How to resolve this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: is the account outside the org? do you have multiple Google accounts logged in?

Comment: The account is WITHIN the org and multiple Google accounts are NOT logged in. Thanks!

Comment: and what happens when you click to switch accounts?

Comment: As I am logged into just one account, when I click "switch accounts", it shows the page "Choose an account to use with Google Drive" and the only option is the same account with which I am logged in. And when click that and continue, It goes back to the screen shown in above screenshot .  If I click "request access", the admin receives an email about giving access to the "scripts file".

Comment: I would recommend you contact [G Suite support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) because the behavior you are having seems odd and you said you didn't make any changes.